# Using Generic class with type String and getting error 'string' must be non-abstract type

Tags: c#, generics

I have a simple generic class as follows:

```
public class DataResponse<T> where T : new()
{
public DataResponse()  
{
    this.Data = new List<T>();
    IsSuccessful = true;
}

public bool IsSuccessful { get; set; }
public string[] ErrorMessages { get; set; }
public List<T> Data { get; set; }
}
```

It works just fine for every custom type I use, however in once instance I have a collection of data that is one field.  Rather than make custom class with one field I would make the type string.  Doing so however returns the error:

```
var response = new DataResponse<String>();
```

'string' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'DataResponse'

*UPDATE*
I had added the where T : new() in response to encountering the problem originally.  Removing it solved it because it caused the IDE to highlight the correct line that was actually giving me the problem.  The line causing the error was to a method that does have the new() constraint.

Apparently its an entirely different call on a method

Comment: Why did you set where T as new()?

Comment: According to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), `System.String` does **not** have a parameterless constructor. Where do you see one?

Comment: _The type string has a parameterless contructor._  No it does not - [String Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.string.aspx)

Comment: @Gandarez I had actually added the T : new() as a result of hitting the error and seeing that as the common solution.  It was only later I realized that IDE was showing the error on the incorrect line.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [`new`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx) constraint

```
where T : new()
```

requires type `T` to have public default constructor:

> The **new** constraint specifies that any type argument in a generic class declaration must have a public parameterless constructor. To use the new constraint, the type cannot be abstract.

`string` does not have one.

Try to remove `where T : new()` from

```
public class DataResponse<T> where T : new()
```

Answer (score 4):

This happens because String **doesn't** have public parameterless constructor which is required by :[new()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx). You can confirm it here [String Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx)

You should modify the code to this:

```
public class DataResponse<T>
{
public DataResponse()  
{
    this.Data = new List<T>();
    IsSuccessful = true;
}

public bool IsSuccessful { get; set; }
public string[] ErrorMessages { get; set; }
public List<T> Data { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This was a combination of an IDE error and a "dumb" on my part.  I was thinking "I make new strings all the time without parameters."  I always explain to people how strings are immutable when they start concatenating them and here I forgot it myself in a different instance.

Answer (score 3):

> The new constraint specifies that any type argument in a generic class declaration must have a public parameterless constructor. To use the new constraint, the type cannot be abstract.

String does not have a parameterless constructor.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

String doesn't have public parameter less constructor which is required for :new() and  To use the new constraint, the type cannot be abstract.

For your reference : String Class

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_strings.htm